# reverse sorting gone wrong in python

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to create a script, that will get a tuple, sort it by value AND by name- for example if I have:

(('apple', 5), ('tv', 500), ('bee', 1000), ('cat', 500))

I want it to return:

['bee', 'cat', 'tv', 'apple']

so that the item with the biggest number will be first, but if two items have the same value the one that is lexicographically smaller will appear first.
this is my code:

```
def find_k_most_expensive_products(data, k):
    executed_file = executeMtmikya(data)
    sorted_prices_tup = sorted(executed_file[2], reverse=True, key=lambda element: 
                              (executed_file[2][1], executed_file[2][0]))
    best_sellers = []

    print("------------")
    print("this is the sorted prices_tup: ")
    print(sorted_prices_tup)
    print("------------")
    for i in sorted_prices_tup:
        while k > 0:
            best_sellers.append(i[1])
            print("k is- ")
            print(k)
            break
        k -= 1
    return best_sellers
```

But this is what I get instead, given:

{'apple': '5', 'tv': '500', 'bee': '1000'}

```
------------
this is the sorted prices_tup: 
[('5', 'apple'), ('500', 'tv'), ('1000', 'bee')]
------------
k is- 
3
k is- 
2
k is- 
1
['apple', 'tv', 'bee']
```

Why isn't it working as expected?

Comment: Lexicographically smaller meaning it is further down on the alphabet? Also, is the input a tuple like you specify?

Comment: So your key function completely ignores the element and you expect that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you got a hint, you need to use the `key` parameter of`sorted`. You however did not do it correctly as your lambda does not use the object that is passed as parameter.

One option is to take the opposite of the number as first key for reverse sorting, and the word as second key for lexicographic sorting:

```
t = (('apple', 5), ('tv', 500), ('bee', 1000), ('cat', 500))

[x for x,_ in sorted(t, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))]
```

Output: `['bee', 'cat', 'tv', 'apple']`

Comment: When you return a tuple for comparison, does it match by comparing the values in the tuple one-by-one? so like (1,0) is ahead of (1,1)

Comment: @Richard Yes it sorts tuples by first item and by second in case of a tie, and so on if more items

Answer (score -1):

try sorted:

```
def sort_by_second(arr):
    return sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (-1*x[1],x[0]),reverse=False)

arr = [('apple', 5), ('tv', 500), ('bee', 1000), ('cat', 500)]

print(list(map(lambda x:x[0],sort_by_second(arr))))
```

output:

```
[bee', 'cat', 'tv', 'apple']
```